# How can we highlight weekdays in the time series ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, dayofweek

Is there a way, we can highlight the week days somehow ?
Since it varies each day and month 
for e.g. 
1st Day of Jan might be Tuesday but 
1st Day of Feb need not be same day
therefore, cannot use facet at all

But is there a way to high light when we have facet_grid as
month and year
**Is there a way to highlight weekday on such plot !!!**

Please consider the reprex

```
library(tidyverse)
# Dataset available @ 
# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/shampoo.csv
data = read_csv("shampoo.csv")

data %>% #glimpse()
  mutate(date = as.Date(Month, format = "%d-%m"),
         month = format(as.Date(date), format = "%m"),
         week_day = weekdays(as.Date(date)),
         Month = NULL) %>%
 # filter(date < as.Date("2019-02-01")) %>%
ggplot(aes(date,Sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +# geom_point()+
  facet_grid(vars(week_day),vars(month))
```

As you can see in the code above it is not possible somehow high light the weekday on the plot ! But isnt it possible, somehow ?

Comment: By weekday, you mean Mon - Fri, excluding weekends (Sat - Sun)?

Comment: There does not appear to be weekday-level data in shampoo.csv. And more to the point, what do you mean by "highlight weekdays"? On the facets? The axes? Coloring the line differently?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your plot on a variable:

```r
 your_plot <- data %>% #glimpse()
  mutate(date = as.Date(Month, format = "%d-%m"),
         month = format(as.Date(date), format = "%m"),
         week_day = weekdays(as.Date(date)),
         Month = NULL) %>%
  # filter(date < as.Date("2019-02-01")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date,Sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vars(week_day),vars(month))
```

2. Add a theme to change the grid title ( weekdays + weekends) to bold

```r
# Add a theme to change the weekdays bold as follows 
your_plot + theme(
    strip.text.y = element_text(
    face = "bold"
  )
)
```

Just to show you the output on the basis of the sample data you shared, 
[image: weekdays_highlight]

As you can see from the output, the only weekdays data available from the plot is highlighted unless you're working on a different set of data.

Comment: Actually, this code will bold the grid but doesnt really high light weekdays ...
geom_line becomes disconnected
For e.g. 

```

your_plot <- data %>% #glimpse()
  mutate(date = as.Date(Month, format = "%d-%m"),
         month = format(as.Date(date), format = "%m"),
         week_day = weekdays(as.Date(date)),
         Month = NULL) %>%
  # filter(date < as.Date("2019-02-01")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date,Sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(vars(week_day),vars(month))

your_plot + theme(
  strip.text.y = element_text(
    face = "bold"
  )
)

Comment: Would have been easier to show a sample of the output you'r expecting.